# Using WindowsFormsHost in COM addin throws ApplicationException following windows update and office upgrade

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, office-interop, windowsformshost

I have been using the following xaml to host a windows forms control inside of my WPF dialog:

```
<Grid x:Name="ConnectionGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,15" MinWidth="730">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsConnectionHost" Visibility="Visible"></WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

This gets populated at run time like this:

```
var host = WinFormsConnectionHost;
host.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
host.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
host.Child = winformsControl;
StyleHostedWinFormsControl(winformsControl);
```

Following a recent updates for Windows and Microsoft Office this is throwing the following exception for some of our users.

```
  Hosted HWND must be a child window of the specified parent. (InvalidOperationException)

AutoTag version: 16.5.0.14
Office: 16 (32-bit), WORD
Windows: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0 (64-bit), GC memory: 26,954,252

Stack trace:
  Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
  Message: Hosted HWND must be a child window of the specified parent.
    Stack: at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
at System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(DependencyObject uie, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(Object sender, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual child)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(UIElement value)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.UseContentTemplate.BuildVisualTree(FrameworkElement container)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
at System.Windows.Window.Show()
at AutoTag.net.windward.autotag.Framework.DataSourceOptions_Click(OfficeDocument doc)
at AutoTag.net.windward.autotag.menu.AutoTagMenu.DataSourceOptions(OfficeDocument doc)
```

Our product is part of an office COM addin and I was able to reproduce this by setting up the following environment:

Windows 10 1809 (build 17763.557)

Microsoft Office 2019 Professional Plus 1906 (Build 11727.20230)

I've also tried to add the WindowsFormsHost programatically like below, but I received the same exception apon adding it to the grid.

```
ConnectionGrid.Children.Clear();
var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
host.Child = winformsControl;
host.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
host.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
StyleHostedWinFormsControl(winformsControl);
ConnectionGrid.Children.Add(host);
```

This issue seems to only occur using the latest Office update.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2733836a-4034-44c0-baf9-149630c2d92a/setting-a-window-as-the-owner-of-a-form?forum=wpf

Comment: Have you tried to set the parent window handle for the windows form control?

Comment: Unfortunately setting the parent doesn't appear to have any effect. This error appears to only occur when the addin is running in Office 2019 1906. It runs fine with earlier versions of Office.

Comment: I also tried using Dispatch.Invoke() to pass adding the winformshost to my dialog off to the UI wtih no luck.